# Place sendmail on a timer

Tags: bash, unix, cron

I have this bash script that checks for a running process among other items. If it errors out then it issues the sendmail command to notify the user. My problem is this piece of sendmail code resides in a larger script that is set in CRON for 5 minutes intervals to check for the processes.

How do I tell the script to only send the email every hour even though the CRON is running every 5 minutes?

One idea I had was to create a CRON entry for the sendmail and uncomment and comment it each time it needs to send the email?

[Bash script to monitor process and sendmail if failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289768/bash-script-to-monitor-process-and-sendmail-if-failed)

If you the code I can post the entire script but it is 111 lines long above is the excerpt from another question I asked and was answered

Answer (score 0):

You could create a flag file to monitor if the email was sent.

Example:

```
FLAG_EMAIL="/tmp/email_already_sent_this_hour" #choose what ever path you want
find $FLAG_EMAIL -mmin +60 -delete #check if flag file older than 60 minute and delete it
if [ -f $FLAG_EMAIL ] ; then
  sendmail....
  touch $FLAG_EMAIL
fi
```

You may need to play around with the find command and you may need to use "-exec rm -f {} \;" instead of -delete

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go and see what I can come up with