# Linux Hadoop Services monitoring tool and restart if down

Tags: linux, performance, hadoop, hadoop2

I have configured Hadoop 2.7.5 with Hbase. It is a 5 system cluster in fully distributed mode. I have to monitor Hadoop/Hbase daemons and want to start some action (e.g. mail ) if some daemon goes down. Is there any built-in solution.
Also I want to start Hadoop at boot time. How can I do this ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you aren't using major dists like Cloudera or Hortonworks, they have this feature built into their stack.

For automated restarts a boot time, you can use the init.d (or systemd)

and example of emailing out in the event of failure there is scripting solution in this answer [Bash script to monitor process and sendmail if failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289768/bash-script-to-monitor-process-and-sendmail-if-failed)

In enterprise organisation, most will have a monitoring solution in place such as tivoli, which you can hook into.

Comment: You are right, I am not using major dists. The solution you have provided (script) is only for single system and not for complete cluster

Comment: You need to monitor each of the processes and look for hung status's as well, ie the process is active but it not working as expected (even Cloudera or hortonworks do this in every situation).   I would consider this a non-trivial task.  I have used ganglia in the past with some successes.

Comment: A simple approach would be to write the pid of the process on startup to a file hbase.sh & echo $! > hbase.pid and do that for every startup and shut down script. then use cron to run every 5 minutes to check for the existence of all the pids and email out if one isn't running

Comment: Thanks for guide. Sir I have already this solution but I want looking some open-source solution